# Как пофиксить это? Array type expected; found: 'java.lang.String'

Tags: java, массивы, строки

```
public static int checkup (String first, String second) {
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    if(first.length() != second.length()) return 0;
    for(int i=0; i<first.length(); i++)
    {
        char c1 = first[i];
        char c2 = second[i];

        for (int j = i; j < first.length(); j++) {
            if ((c1 == first[j] && c2 != second[j]) ||
                    (c1 != first[j] && c2 == second[j]))
            {
                return 0;
            }
        }
    }
    return 1;
}
```

`char c1 = first[i]; char c2 = second[i];` - хочу сделать инициализацию таким образом, но выдает ошибку

Comment: Когда выдает ошибку, нужно в первую очередь читать про ошибку, а не строчить вопрос в интернет.

Comment: Ничего страшного ведь не случилось, одно другому не мешает !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Array type expected; found: 'java.lang.String'
```

говорит сама за себя. Вы пытаетесь индексировать String как массив, а это неправильно. Вам нужно:

```
char c1 = first.charAt(i);
char c2 = second.charAt(i);
```

Comment: Благодарю ! Все работает

Answer (score 1):

```
char c1 = first.charAt(i);
char c2 = second.charAt(i);
```